# Accept autocorrection after input

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

My user enter a text in a `UITextField` then press a `UIBarButtonItem` to confirm.

If there's a autocorrection suggestion when the user tap the  `UIBarButtonItem`, it is not accepted. How do I accept it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling:

```
[textfield resignFirstResponder];
```

on your textfield, when the user hits your button.